# Upper bound but does not have a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to be the set of all sequences of integers. Where every element $x$ is of the following form: $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...)$ with $\forall n\in \mathbb N, x_{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

We order the set as follows: $x\lneq y\Leftrightarrow$ the first non-zero entry of $y-z$ is positive. Where we denote subtractions as term by term such that: $y-z$ corresponds to the sequence $(y_{1}-x_{1},y_{2}-x_{2},...,)$

Assume that $(\mathbb Z^\mathbb N, \lneq)$ forms a totally ordered set.

I’m trying to find an example of some element in this totally ordered set that has an upper bound but does not have a supremum.

So far I’ve been unable to come up with one, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You probably want to find a set of elements that has an upper bound but no supremum.  Each element is the supremum of the singleton set containing it.  In your definition of the order $z$ should be $x$

Comment: Hint:  $(0,x_2,x_3,x_4,........) < (1, w_2, w_3,w_4,........)$.

Comment: @fleablood Wouldn't it be $(x_{1},x_{2},.......,0)<(w_{1},w_{2},....,1)$ since we're talking about upper bounds? I understand how this would create an upper bound but I don't see how this would imply it would not have a supremum?

Comment: I'm not claiming either of those are upper bounds of anything.  I'm saying that $(0,x_2, x_3, x_4,......) < (1, w_2, w_3, w_4,.....)$ etc. is always true.  It is, isn't it? $y -x = (1-0, x_2-w_2, x_3-w_3,......) = (1,x_2-w_2,x_3-w_3,......)$, and the frist non zero entry is $1$ and $1 > 0$.  So $(0,x_2,x_3,......,=) < (0,w_2, w_3,.....)$.

Comment: "I don't see how this would imply it would not have a supremum?"  Well, what *is* the supremum of $\{x=(x_1, x_2,.....)| x_1=0\}$?

Comment: @fleablood I don’t think it would have one right? Since $(0, x_{2}, x_{3},……) does not have a defined upper bound and thus have no supremum?

Comment: Of course it has *an* upper bound.  $(1,0,0,0....)$ is an upper bound.  And $(\frac 12, 7, -14.5, \sqrt{\pi},.....)$ is an upper bound, and $(0.00000003, -5$million$,-7$billion$, ....)$ is also upper bound.  But what is the *least* upper bound?  Is there a least upper bound?

Comment: " Wouldn't it be (x1,x2,.......,0)<(w1,w2,....,1) since we're talking about upper bounds? "  $(x_1, x_2,.....,0) > (w_1, w_2,....,1)$ if $x_1> w_2$.  And $(x_1, x_2,.....,0) < (w_1, w_2,....,1)$ if $x_1< w_1$.  And if $x_1= w_1$ then we don't know which is larger or smaller unless we know how $x_2$ and $w_2$ compare.

Comment: "I’m trying to find an example of some element in this totally ordered set that has an upper bound "  *elements* do not have upper bounds.  ***SETS*** have upper bound.  Elements are what the are.  There are values larger than them, and there are values less than them but they don't have bounds.